# Javascript set window.name - issue in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, variables, window, global-variables

I have the following scenario.

Website A is opening Website B using `window.open("Website B", "windowName");`

In Website B I have the following code:

```
<script>
  window.name='';  
  window.location.href = 'Website C'; 
</script>
```

In Website C I have in Firefox and Chrome (all versions) `window.name` equal to '', but in IE(versions 9, 10, 11) it is equal to 'windowName'.

Can someone explain why? I need an workaround to always have `window.name = ''` when I get to Website C. I cannot use windows.open in Website B to open Website C, I need to use window.location.

Source coded added:

index.html (Site A)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Page A</title>
<head>
<script>
    function test2(){
        window.open("index2.html","Some window name","width=500,height=500");
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" onClick="test2();">
</body>
</html>
```

index2.html (Site B)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Page B</title>
<head>
<script>
    document.write("initial window name: [" + window.name + "]<br/><br/>");
    window.name=""; //we set it to empty string
    document.write("after we set window.name to empty string: [" + window.name + "]"); //all fine in all browsers, shows nothing
    document.location= 'index3.html';
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

index3.html (Site C)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Page C</title>
<head>
<script>
    document.write("initial window name: [" + window.name + "]"); //OK in Firefox (shows nothing). Not OK in IE, shows "Some window name"
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Added the source code that proves the problem and asked for someone to provide an workaround. Please reopen.

Comment: Unable to reproduce the problem (using various browsers including MSIE6) although in my case, I was setting the name / calling the redirect in seperate Javascript calls rather than synchronously - does it stil happen if you invoke change document.location via a setTimeout after changing the name?

Comment: On IE (all versions 9-11) on Page C it still shows window.name = 'Some window name' after adding something like on Page B: setTimeout(doRedirect, 10000); Please note that I only have access to Page B code, so Page A and Page C I cannot change to solve this.

Comment: I can confirm that using on Page A: window.name = "Some window name"; document.location="index2.html"; instead of window.open() makes the issue go away. Please note that I only have access to Page B code, so Page A and Page C I cannot change to solve this.

Comment: I have experienced the same issue in IE11. I think it's down to the way Internet Explorer manages it's tabs internally.

My tests have shown that after changing the name property of the window in the document, when the URL of that tab changes, IE re-asserts the original name it specified to the name property.

Furthermore, if you duplicate a tab, IE will re-use tabs that were previously closed! I've found this to be the case as tabs that I had previously named and closed had reappeared when duplicating tabs (Ctrl+K). This also happens with anchors with a target of "_blank".

Answer (score 4):

According to the MSDN documentation, the `name` property is changeable:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I tried to change the `name` property, and it works fine in IE9:

http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/5cBBy/1/

I also tried to change it to an empty string, and that works:

http://jsfiddle.net/5cBBy/2/

So, there is likely something else that is wrong with your code.

Comment: Indeed on Website B, after I set up window.name = '', alert(window.name) it shows empty string, but after the redirect somehow window.name is set back to its original value. So on Website C it is again equal to 'windowName'. Which I need to avoid.

Comment: I have updated the initial post with source code for site a,b and c which shows what the problem is on IE vs. Mozilla. Anyone can explain this behavior and provide an workaround?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found out that you need to rename the window AFTER you set the new window.location. That worked for me!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14281982)

Comment: Why not? You can read in the comments that the existing problem is, that the window.name is reset to the oringinal name after changing its location. This can be fixed by setting the window.name property right after the change of window.location (or in this case document.location). That way the window will keep the new name even after the location change.

Comment: Can you provide the source code? If I change the document.location the redirection is already done. How can I change the name then if the location is not under our control?

Comment: Sure, I did it simply that way:

Comment: 'function NavigateHome() {
            window.location.assign("MyNewLocation.aspx");
            window.name = "MyNewName" + new Date().toISOString();
        }'